# Map key for multiple combinations in neovim

Tags: neovim

I'm using a Swedish/Finnish keyboard layout and am trying to map the `{`,`}`,`[`,`]` characters to a more convenient key.

I tried putting the following lines in my **init.lua**

```lua
vim.keymap.set({ "i", "o" }, "å", "[", { noremap = true })
vim.keymap.set({ "i", "o" }, "¨", "]", { noremap = true })
vim.keymap.set({ "i", "o" }, "Å", "{", { noremap = true })
vim.keymap.set({ "i", "o" }, "^", "}", { noremap = true })
```

which works well in insert mode but not in combination with other commands. For instance, when I press `fÅ` I want the cursor to move to `{` but what happens is that it moves to `Å` instead.

Any idea how to solve this without explicitly mapping every single combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for both `tå` and `ciå`.

```lua
for _, entry in ipairs({
    { { "l", "c" }, "å", "[" },
    { { "l", "c" }, "¨", "]" },
    { { "l", "c" }, "Å", "{" },
    { { "l", "c" }, "^", "}" },
    { { "o", "v" }, "iå", "i[" },
    { { "o", "v" }, "i¨", "i]" },
    { { "o", "v" }, "iÅ", "i{" },
    { { "o", "v" }, "i^", "i}" },
    { { "o", "v" }, "aå", "a[" },
    { { "o", "v" }, "a¨", "a]" },
    { { "o", "v" }, "aÅ", "a{" },
    { { "o", "v" }, "a^", "a}" },
}) do
    local modes, from, to = unpack(entry)
    vim.keymap.set(modes, from, to, { noremap = true })
end
vim.opt.iminsert = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```lua
vim.keymap.set({"l"}, "å", "[", { noremap = true })
vim.opt.iminsert = 1
```

The `lmap` (language-mapping) applies to the argument of the commands that accept a text character, such as "r" and "f" (see `:h language-mapping`).

The `iminsert` setting is for switching on `lmap` (see https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10843 and `:h iminsert`).

When switched on by setting `iminsert`, `lmap` is claimed to also apply to:

1. **insert mode**
2. **command-line mode** (`:`)
3. **search pattern** (`/`, `?`)

However, with a simple trial, I noticed that the **command-line mode** does not seem to respect `lmap`, so `cmap` might be needed.

In summary, the below settings enables the mappings:

1. when using `f` and `r` (`lmap`)
2. in insert mode (`lmap`)
3. in search pattern (`lmap`)
4. in command-line mode
5. in operator-pending mode

```lua
vim.keymap.set({ "l", "c", "o" }, "å", "[", { noremap = true })
vim.keymap.set({ "l", "c", "o" }, "¨", "]", { noremap = true })
vim.keymap.set({ "l", "c", "o" }, "Å", "{", { noremap = true })
vim.keymap.set({ "l", "c", "o" }, "^", "}", { noremap = true })
vim.opt.iminsert = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried your solution, for some reason it works for combinations such as `t` `å` (go to [) but not for `c` `i` `å` (change inner [).